# 'Cannot read property of null' inside a pipe - Angular 7

Tags: angular

I trying to pipe the info that i am receiving from my server. Everything is works fine but the only issue is that i am receiving 'Cannot read property of null'  on the component init

```
 <span [outerHTML]="contract?.content | replaceLineBreaks"></span>
```

Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


    @Pipe({name: 'replaceLineBreaks'})
    export class ReplaceLineBreaks implements PipeTransform {
      transform(value: string): string {
          return value.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `contract?.content`. That means in the first change detection cycle, this data will be `undefined` while the HTTP request completes.

Then you should handle the `undefined` case in your pipe with something like:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'replaceLineBreaks'})
export class ReplaceLineBreaks implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): string {
        return value ? value.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') :  "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but its still the same
`export class ReplaceLineBreaks implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return value ? value.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') :  "";
  }`

`<span [outerHTML]="contract.content | replaceLineBreaks"></span>`

Comment: which property is null? did you paste the full error message?

Comment: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined`

Comment: Because now you removed the `?` after contract, so you're trying to access `content` although `contract` is null. You cannot access a property on a null value, whether you're in a template or a pipe or anywhere else. Null values don't have properties.

Comment: No. Just use the code you had in your question, but check that the value is truthy before trying to call replace() on it. Just like the answer explains. It doesn't tell you anywhere to replace contract?.content by contract.content.

Comment: `<span [outerHTML]="contract?.content | replaceLineBreaks"></span>`

`export class ReplaceLineBreaks implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return value ? value.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') : "";
  }`

`ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element has no parent node.`

Comment: That's another problem, feel free to accept my answer if it helped you. My guess on your new problem is that you should use `innerHTML` instead of `outerHTML`

Comment: OK. So now the error is fixed. You have *another*, unrelated error.